# org.json.JSONException: Value of Feedback type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray while converting jsonstring to object

Tags: java, android, json

I am new in android development..I just want to remove object from jsonstring.
I have jsonstring and I am converting string into json object and then array..remove object from jsonobject and again convert into jsonstring ,save that string into db..

but I got error that `org.json.JSONException: Value Feedback of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray`

Here is my code:

```
 public JSONArray convertjsonstringtoarray()
{
    JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray();
    String select_json= customizeAdapter.selectCustomizeEntry_jsonmodified();
    Log.e("Json String Select",select_json);
    try {
        JSONObject jsnobject = new JSONObject(select_json);
        jsonArray = new JSONArray("Feedback");

        jsonArray = jsnobject.getJSONArray("Feedback");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject explrObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        }

    }catch (Exception j){
        Log.e("Exception JSON", j.toString());
    }
    RemoveJSONArray(jsonArray);
    Log.e("JSOn ARRAY",jsonArray.toString());
    return jsonArray;

}
public static JSONArray RemoveJSONArray( JSONArray jarray) {

    JSONArray Njarray=new JSONArray();
    try{
        for(int i=0;i<jarray.length();i++){
            if(i!=1)
                Njarray.put(jarray.get(i));
        }
    }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    return Njarray;
}
```

Here my select_json is :

```
{"id":0,"name":null,"email":null,"fields":{"Feedback":[{"min":"1","max":"1000","visible":"1","params":"","access":"","registration":"1","type":"text","option1":"","id":1,"option2":"","option3":"","option4":"","fieldcode":"FIELDght66yh","name":"ght66yh","value":"","ordering":1,"tips":"ght66yh","required":"0","published":"1","searchable":"1","options":""},{"min":"1","max":"1000","visible":"1","params":"","access":"","registration":"1","type":"text","option1":"","id":2,"option2":"","option3":"","option4":"","fieldcode":"FIELDbgfhtuu","name":"bgfhtuu","value":"","ordering":2,"tips":"bgfhtuu","required":"0","published":"1","searchable":"1","options":""}]}}
```

Comment: `jsonArray = new JSONArray("Feedback");` is probably your problem, as the String "Feedback" is no JSONArray

Comment: ok..I agree with you..so what is correct syntax

Comment: just leave this line completly out.

Comment: and btw. you should follow the Java coding guidelines, for better readability and to not confuse the SO syntax highlightning. method names should start with a small letter (removeJSONArray)

Comment: If i remove that line,then how should I convert into array?method name should be small character , for this you are absolutely right but here problem is not that..

Comment: you receive the JSONArray by running the `getJSONArray("Feedback")` method on your JSONObject. is there still a problem?

Comment: Error: No value for Feedback

Comment: well sorry. Feedback is inside another JSONObject, namely fields. therefore you have to extract the fields object before you can access the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code to parse json response .

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);// here response is your json string

        String id = jsonObject.getString("id");
        /**
         * Same way you can get other string value
         */ 
        JSONObject obj =  jsonObject.getJSONObject("fields");

        JSONArray array2 = obj.getJSONArray("Feedback");

        for (int i = 0; i < array2.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject2 = array2.getJSONObject(i);
            ///do something here    
        }   

} catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just create the object of jsonarray .then assign **jsnobject.getJSONArray("Feedback")** to that..no need to pass "Feedback" string inside the constructor

```
public JSONArray convertjsonstringtoarray()
{
JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray();
String select_json= customizeAdapter.selectCustomizeEntry_jsonmodified();
Log.e("Json String Select",select_json);
try {
    JSONObject jsnobject = new JSONObject(select_json);
    //assume this object "jsnobject" is contain the below json
    //dont know what's this select_json is
    /*"{
    "Feedback": [
        {
            "min": "1",
            "max": "1000",
            "visible": "1",
            "params": "",
            "access": "",
            "registration": "1",
            "type": "text",
            "option1": "",
            "id": 1,
            "option2": "",
            "option3": "",
            "option4": "",
            "fieldcode": "FIELDght66yh",
            "name": "ght66yh",
            "value": "",
            "ordering": 1,
            "tips": "ght66yh",
            "required": "0",
            "published": "1",
            "searchable": "1",
            "options": ""
        }]}*/
    //jsonArray = new JSONArray("Feedback");//your code is problematic here
    //just create the object lik
    jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    //jsonArray = new JSONObject() //dont know..why you doing that

    jsonArray = jsnobject.getJSONArray("Feedback");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject explrObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    }

}catch (Exception j){
    Log.e("Exception JSON", j.toString());
}
RemoveJSONArray(jsonArray);
Log.e("JSOn ARRAY",jsonArray.toString());
return jsonArray;

}
public static JSONArray RemoveJSONArray( JSONArray jarray) {

JSONArray Njarray=new JSONArray();
try{
    for(int i=0;i<jarray.length();i++){
        if(i!=1)
            Njarray.put(jarray.get(i));
    }
}catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
return Njarray;
}
```

Comment: question already answered. and your answer is wrong, as the JSONArray named Feedback is inside another JSONObject of name fields

Comment: @ceekay ..as Ammy write this.. "jsonArray = jsnobject.getJSONArray("Feedback");" so i assume jsnobject is object is the value for key "fields" ...  and not the outer json...and i've update the answer too...

Comment: The value of select_json is provided, therefore also the one of jsnobject. but nvm with the updated answer its ok (even if the other one is much more compact)